# File upload with react + Vertx

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-redux, vert.x

I am working on a web application and i must upload a file the server which is written in Java + VertX

The endpoint is made like this:

```
private void uploadFromExcel(RoutingContext ctx) {    
    new ImportFromExcel(ctx.getBody(), ctx.vertx()).startImporting(ev->{
        if(ev.failed()){
            ctx.fail(ev.cause());
        }else {
            ctx.response().end();
        }
    });        
}
```

And the frontend like this:

```
<input
   accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
   type="file"
   onChange={this.onUploadFile}
 />
   <label htmlFor="flat-button-file">
     <IconButton component="span">
         <Icon className={'material icons'}>cloud_upload</Icon>
     </IconButton>
   </label>

[...]

onUploadFile = (e) =>{
   const {reduxApi, setError, setWait, removeWait} = this.context
   const { dispatchUploadFile } = this.props

   const fileToUpload = e.target.files[0]

   dispatchUploadFile(reduxApi, fileToUpload , (err,data)=>{
      removeWait()
      //e.target.value = null
      if(err){
        setError(err)
        return
       }
   })

   [...]

   dispatchUploadFile: (reduxApi, file, cb) =>{
      dispatch(reduxApi.actions.cryptoindexUploadExcel.post(null,file,cb))
   }
```

I can upload the file via postman using the Header "Accept-Type":"multipart/form-data". It works fine!

Unfortunatelly I cannot upload the file via react, it throws an error. So I decided to try another solution

```
let  reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = (event)  => {
    let arrayBuffer = event.target.result
    let array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    let binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array)
    console.log(binaryString)

    setWait()
    dispatchUploadFile(reduxApi, array , (err,data)=>{
      removeWait()
      if(err){
        setError(err)
        return
      }
    })

}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileToUpload)
```

This piece of code reads the file but the backend part says "Zero byte long file". Do you have any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that on the server side you have the `BodyHandler` in your router:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
```

Now depending on the way you upload your file it might end up in 2 places:

If it is a `multipart/form-data` it will be available in the context under the `fileUploads()` getter:

```
Set<FileUpload> uploads = routingContext.fileUploads();
// Do something with uploads....
```

It it is a body upload, for example something like AJAX call `application/json` it ends up in the `body()` getter. So be sure that you're using the right headers as they are processed differently both by the browser and server during the upload.

Comment: I think the problem is in in react... it seems that no data is sent!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! The problem was in Frontend. I rewrote the upload method using the XMLTHTTPRequest this way:

```
onUploadFile = (e) =>{
    if(!e.target.files || e.target.files.length==0) return

    const {reduxApi, setError, setWait, removeWait} = this.context
    const fileToUpload = e.target.files[0]

    setWait()

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST', getRootURL() + "/cryptoindex/index/excel")

   xhr.onload = () => {
     removeWait()
     if(xhr.status!=200){
        setError({...xhr, responseJSON: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)})
     }else{
       this.refreshAll()
     }
   }

    xhr.send(fileToUpload)
 }
```

It is not the best solution but it works!